# Add Icon for ToolWindow in WPF

Tags: wpf, window, icons

How can I add an Icon for ToolWindow in WPF?

Just as

```
<Window x:Class="WPFApp.Account"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Accounting Information"
    FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="13"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Width="600" Height="600">
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say ToolWindow?

Comment: Is this a Visual Studio add-in ToolWindow?

Comment: @sauron if any of those solve your issue, you might pick that as the answer

Answer (score 7):

I know that is old but I passed through the same problem now days and I decide to contribute a solution.

You can't use icon with the **WindowStyle** '*ToolWindow*', but you can use '*SingleBorderWindow*' and in property **ResizeMode** the value '*NoResize*'. Now you have the same behavior of '*ToolWindow*' but with icon.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want ToolWindow because it hides the minimize/maximize buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Window.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx) property?

Comment: I don't believe that will work. When the WindowStyle is ToolWindow, the Icon is automatically hidden.